# Launchctl jobs automatically getting unloaded on snow leapord

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, operating-system

We have launchctl jobs loaded on the snow leopard server. Somehow, every few days the jobs gets unloaded and this is causing our periodic jobs not to run. When I logon to the machine, the jobs show up again as loaded in launchctl list.

Did anyone see similar issue before?

- Bala

Answer (score 0):

Are they loaded by the system launchd (as LaunchDaemons), or by the user launchd (as LaunchAgents)? If they're loaded as LaunchAgents, they'll only be loaded when you're logged in. If you run `launchctl list` as a normal user, it'll show LaunchAgents loaded in your session; if you want to see the system LaunchDaemons instead, use `sudo launchctl list`.

Comment: They are loaded as user.

Comment: In that case, they'll always be unloaded when you log out. If you want them to run when you're not logged in, you have to load them as LaunchDaemons instead.